# google map get place id

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want the place_id of the longitude and latitude written on `#latlng` on `#send` click . 
html is here

```
      <input id="latlng" class="controls" type="text"><input id="place_input" class="controls" type="text"><input type="button" id="send" value="send">
      <div id="map_div">
        <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
        <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
```

javascript is here

```
function initAutocomplete() {

  var lat = {lat: 20.593684, lng:  78.96288000000004};
  var markers = [];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: lat,
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
     zoomControl: true,
    scaleControl: true
  });

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    places.forEach(function(place) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        draggable:true
      });
      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(marker);
      document.getElementById("place_input").value = place.geometry.location;

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (marker) {
                document.getElementById("latlng").value = this.getPosition().lat() + ', ' + this.getPosition().lng() ; 
        }); 

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });


   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    addMarker(event.latLng, map);
  });


  function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
   }

  function addMarker(location, map) {   
      if(markers.length == 0){
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    map: map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    draggable:true
              });

            markers.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (marker) {
                document.getElementById("latlng").value =  this.getPosition().lat() + ', ' + this.getPosition().lng() ; 
            });           
       }else{
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    map: map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    draggable:true
              });
            setMapOnAll(null);
            markers = [];
            markers.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (marker) {
                document.getElementById("latlng").value = this.getPosition().lat() + ', ' + this.getPosition().lng() ; 
            });     
       }
  }



  var placename ;

  function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
    var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
    var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
    var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
    geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
            map.setZoom(11);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
            });
            infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
           placename = results[1].formatted_address;
           document.getElementById("place_input").value =  placename;
        } else {
            window.alert('No results found');
        }
        } else {
        window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
    }

    function codeAddress(geocoder,map,infowindow) {
        var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
    var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
        var latitude = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);               
        var longitude = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
        var latlng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

        geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                console.log(results[1].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[1].geometry.location
                });
                console.log(results[1].place_id);
            } else {
                window.alert('No results found');
            }
            } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }



    document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', function() {
        /*geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);*/
        codeAddress(geocoder,map,infowindow);
    });


}
```

This code is not working . It is giving wrong place id. I matched it with google map place id finder.
Want help fast.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think the place id is wrong?  Place ids uniquely identify a place but multiple place ids may refer to the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a guess, but I think the array returned as a response object in the geocoding function has multiple results for each search. You seem to be calling the response object's second closest match with an index of 1. Try:

```
        if (results[0]) {
            console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            console.log(results[0].place_id);
```